# Vue 2 how to return a watcher in a global function

Tags: vue.js, async-await, promise

Hello I have this problem:in main.js I have a global function `getSites`, needed to retrive a list of sites from API.
This function work with async/await and returns data sites asynchronously.
I also have a global variable called `lockSitesLoading` which i set to true when i start to fetch data from API, I need this to prevent client to make a new request to server.
In the first function `getSites` I need to check this variable `lockSitesLoading` and, if it's true, start to watch it till it becomes false. At this point I want to call `getSites` recursively.
The problem starts now, because when i start watch the variable this function doesn't wait for the variable to become false, but returns `undefined`.
Here there is my code:

component.vue:

```
  async mounted() {
    let vm = this;
    const sites = await vm.getSites();
    vm.sites = sites.data
  },
```

main.js:

```
 async getSites() {
      let vm = this;
      if (vm.$store.state.lockSitesLoading) {
        vm.$watch('$store.state.lockSitesLoading', () => vm.getSites());
      } else {
        return vm._getSitesOnline();
        //this is the function that effectively get datas from server
      }
```

I tried to solve it in this way, but doesn't works. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there needs to be a promise to await:

```
  let unwatch;

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    unwatch = vm.$watch('$store.state.lockSitesLoading', loading => {
      if (!loading) {
        resolve();
      }
    }, { immediate: true });
  });

  unwatch();

  await vm._getSitesOnline();
```

Notice that this will result in memory leak if `lockSitesLoading` is blocking the execution for some reason.

This may be cleaner ways to do this with composition API and VueUse composables.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply.
now it throws me an error:
```ReferenceError: Cannot access 'unwatch' before initialization```
Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.
Now errors are gone, but callback's watch doesn't fire, is like there is no watch.

Comment: Found it!
It needs a small change:
 ```if (!loading) {
   resolve();
 }```
we need to check loading if is false, and not true

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if and where do you set `lockSitesLoading = true`

Here is the working example.

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    sites: [],
    lockSitesLoading: false
  },
  actions: {
    async loadSites(context) {
        context.state.lockSitesLoading = true;    
        const sites = await context.dispatch('getSites');
        context.state.sites = sites.data;
        context.state.lockSitesLoading = false;    
    },
    async getSites(context) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          setTimeout(function(){
            resolve({ data: ['site1', 'site2', 'site3']})              
          },1000)
        })
      }    
  }
})

new Vue(
  { 
    el:'#app',
    store: store,
    async mounted() {
       await this.$store.dispatch('loadSites')
    },
    computed: {
      sites() { return this.$store.state.sites },
      lockSitesLoading() { return this.$store.state.lockSitesLoading }
    },
    watch: {
      lockSitesLoading(newVal, oldVal) {
          console.log(`lockSitesLoading: ${oldVal} -> ${newVal}`)
      }
    }    
  }
)
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  sites: {{sites}}<br/>
  lockSitesLoading: {{lockSitesLoading}}
</div>
```

Comment: It's true, i realized now that it's not clear. It becomes true just inside the function _getSitesOnline(), and becomes false in the same function after the answer of the server

Comment: The answer may have a point but doesn't contain the explanation what's changed and why. @PaoloDell'Orti Currently it looks like it could be design problem rather than programmatic. if _getSitesOnline is local method that updates global store, it may belong to a store where it can be aware of its own lockSitesLoading state and getSites calls in a cooordinated way, something like this answer suggests